# How to read frames of a video and write them on another video output using FFMPEG and nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am working on a project where I need to process video frames one at a time in Node.js. I aim to avoid storing all frames in memory or the filesystem due to resource constraints. I plan to use the ffmpeg from child processes for video processing.
I tried reading a video file and then output frames of it in the filesystem first for testing purposes :-

```js
const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', videoFile,
  'testfolder/%04d.png' // Output frames to stdout
]);
```

and the above code works fine, it saves the video frames as png files in the filesystem. Now instead of saving them in the file system, I want to read the frames on at a time and use a image manipulation library and than write the final edited frames to another video as output

I tried this :-

```js
const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', videoFile,
  'pipe:1' // Output frames to stdout
]);

const ffmpegOutputProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', '-',
  'outputFileName.mp4'
  ]);

ffmpegProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // Process the frame data as needed
  console.log('Received frame data:');
  ffmpegOutputProcess.stdin.write(data)
});

ffmpegProcess.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.error(`ffmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
  } else {
    console.log('ffmpeg process successfully completed');
    
  }
});

// Handle errors
ffmpegProcess.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error while spawning ffmpeg:', err);
});
```

But when I tried above code and also some other modifications in the input and output suffix in the command I got problems as below :-

1. ffmpeg process exited with code 1
2. The final output video was corrupted when trying to initializing the filters for commands :-

```js
const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
 '-i', videoFile,
 '-f', 'rawvideo',
 '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
 'pipe:1' // Output frames to stdout
]);

const ffmpegOutputCommand = [
 '-f', 'rawvideo',
 '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
 '-s', '1920x1080',
 '-r', '30',
 '-i', '-',
 '-c:v', 'libx264',
 '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
 outputFileName
];
```

Thank you so much in advance :)